# Sitecore And Multiple Visual Studio Solutions

Tags: sitecore

I would like to reuse one installation of Sitecore every time I need to make code changes.  I currently have a branch to fix a problem, but now I need to create another branch to fix another problem.  The problems are in different websites so I need to keep the seperate branches.  I really do not want to create another Sitecore installation for this second branch.  Is there a way to "swap" out these solutions and "reuse" the same Sitecore installation?

Comment: It sounds like you can just remove your custom code that you had in your first branch to get the install back to the original state, then add in your new code via a new branch. Unless I'm misunderstanding your scenario. If I am, please update your question with maybe your version control tree structure and your file system of where files are for your site. Also, it might be easier to help you if you're more specific about what exactly you're "fixing" -- a layout, a sublayout, utility code business logic, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark Ursino's comment about removing the code got me to thinking.  Since the solution binded to the Sitecore installation resides in the Website folder, I'll map both solutions to somewhere arbitrary, like "Sitecore Dev Folder", and then map the branch I'm working in to the Website folder of the Sitecore installation. When I change the mapping, the solution will download from TFS into the Website folder (blowing away the existing solutuion.) And that's how I can achieve the "swapping" of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, we need more info here to really answer the question.

But... in general, I would advise you not to do this.  Creating a new Sitecore installation is a piece of cake with the installer, and not exactly resource intensive.  You could have it use the same DB if necessary to make things easier.

Mixing two different branches with the same Sitecore instance... it seems inevitable that something would get "F'd up", to use the technical term.

Comment: You're right about the install being "a peice of cake", but it's installing the packages that takes time.

Comment: What's in the packages? Be as specific as possible